# Highcharts: How to show marker in X range chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to plot a marker in X range chart. (For example: After Sprint4, I would like to show a circular milestone in DEV category). Refer following JS fiddle.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/jgn9bLak/56/

```
{
    type: "scatter",
    x: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 3),
    //x2: Date.UTC(2014, 4, 31),
    y: 0,
    marker: {
      enabled: true,
      symbol: 'circle',
      fillColor: "yellow",
      lineWidth: 1
    }
  },
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you make a separate series for scatter-points to keep these circular milestones since xRange does not support this point format. For example:

```
series: [{
  name: 'milestones'
  type: 'scatter',
  stickyTracking: false,
  marker: {
    enabled: true,
    symbol: 'circle',
    fillColor: "yellow",
    lineWidth: 5,
    radius: 10
  },
  data: [{
    x: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 3),
    y: 0,
  }]
},
...
]
```

You could also change marker per point, to have different shapes for different points. In addition to this, you would need to change your tooltip formatter like this:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    if (this.series.name != 'milestones') {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/jgn9bLak/90/

Answer (score 0):

As @ewolden said you need to create a another serie, here is another example:

https://jsfiddle.net/code4jhon/oL83jty5/

```
 {
    // Second series
    name: 'Granted',
    color: 'green',
    id: 'blue',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'diamond'
    },
    dataRaw: [{
      y: 1,
      xRanges: [
        // first value: from; second value: to
        [toMs(2006, 10), toMs(2006, 10)]
      ]
    }]
  }
```